# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline with Jenkinsfile not in repository

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

When a Multibranch Pipeline is created in Jenkins, one of the configuration options is: `Build Configuration`, where you set the location of a `Jenkinsfile` relative to the root of the branch. For example, if you have  `Jenkinsfile` at the root of your repo, you would simply set `Script Path` to `Jenkinsfile`. Then, when branches are detected and jobs created for these branches, Jenkins knows where to find the `Jenkinsfile` script and all is well.

This works fine, but lets say I wanted to have **all of this functionality without having a Jenkinsfile in my repository**. I still want to detect all of the branches and run a job for each of them, but I would prefer if the Jenkinsfile resided somewhere else (eg. a seperate repo).

Is there any way to accomplish this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/

> The Multibranch Pipeline project type enables you to implement different Jenkinsfiles for different branches of the same project. In a Multibranch Pipeline project, Jenkins automatically discovers, manages and executes Pipelines for branches **which contain a Jenkinsfile** in source control.

Looks like it is not possible, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do basically defeats the whole purpose of Multibranch Pipeline. This plugin was meant to allow you one Jenkinsfile per branch, so that in each branch you could modify instructions of how to build this branch (configuration as a code).

If one Jenkinsfile is good for you, you should run it as a regular Pipeline job -- with e.g. branch name as parameter.

Comment: I see my company implemented such a pipeline. When I onboard my app, it only created some configure files in my repo, there is no Jenkinsfile. As in Jenkins, I have no admin right so can't see how it's configured. Not sure if it's using Jenkins library or some other approach.